# How can I restore a MySql database dump direct from S3?

Tags: ubuntu, backup, mysql, gzip, amazon-s3

I have a gzipped database backup stored on S3 and would like to restore it to MySql without having to first download it due to disk space constraints. I tried the two  commands below but got `gzip: stdin: not in gzip format` both times.

Version 1:

```
s3cmd get s3://mybucket/mydbbackup.sql.gz | gzip -d | mysql -u root -p
```

Version 2:

```
s3cmd get s3://mybucket/mydbbackup.sql.gz - | gzip -d | mysql -u root -p
```

Comment: Pipe it directly into less or something.  Do you see something that looks like a mysqldump?  What happens if you do `s3cmd get s3://mybucket/mydbbackup.sql.gz - | od -x`?

Comment: I get a lot of hex output `0000000 7327 3a33 2f2f 6877 7265 7465 626f 7975`. What should I be looking for?

Comment: the `s3cmd ... | od -x` was just to double check you were getting anything at all, and not an error or something, anyway if that gives you something see what you get with your command line, without the pipe into mysql.  So `s3cmd get s3://mybucket/mydbbackup.sql.gz - | gzip -d`  What you see should look like a bunch of SQL statements.

Comment: Even this gives me the same error `s3cmd get s3://mybucket/mydbbackup.sql.gz - | zcat`

Comment: Hrm, I am running low on ideas.  How exactly did you make this backup?

Comment: I think the `s3cmd` output is corrupt. The restore worked when I switched to `curl`

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me (in case other people are now looking at this):

```
aws s3 cp $DATA_LOCATION - | gunzip -c | mysql --host=$MYSQL_HOST --user=$MYSQL_USER --password=$MYSQL_PASS --database=$database
```